# How to pass form input and music from one page to another using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been stuck on this for a while now. I have the first page which includes this form:

```
<form id="user" name="user" method="GET" action="the-tell-tale-heart.html">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="soundtrack" id="st1" value="oldMansion">Soundtrack 1
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="soundtrack" id="st2" value="champion">Soundtrack 2
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I want the user to have entered the name and chosen a soundtrack. The submit button would redirect them to a second page (the-tell-tale-heart.html) where their name would appear at the top saying "Hello, " and the soundtrack they chose would play.

I've been told to use parse URL to get this info on the second page. I only want to use javascript, no php or perl. This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
    var name="";
    var url=document.URL;
    function findName(){
       var re=/(name)\=(.*)?&/;
       name=url.match(re);
       name=name.substring(5);
       alert(name);
    }
    findName();
    var oldMansion = new Audio('music/stories-of-the-old-mansion.mp3');
    var champion = new Audio('music/champion.mp3');
    // play one or the other depending on which the user chooses IF STATEMENTS :D
    if {
                oldMansion.play();

    }
    else {
                champion.play();

    }

</script>
```

I'm not sure what the conditions for the music would be.

EDIT:
So the findName() function actually gets this part of the URL:

```
?name=izzy&soundtrack=champion
```

and cuts it down to this on the second page:

```
izzy&,name,izzy
```

I would just like to get "izzy" and put that on the top of the page.

Comment: You'll have to parse the query string and check the value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// ... your code
if(url.indexOf('soundtrack=oldMansion') != -1) oldMansion.play();
else champion.play();
```

Comment: Is there possibly a way to use this same method for the name input even though it's a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript, you really should just initiate the music on the page you're already on. There's no point in submitting a form to another page - that's the whole point of javascript - making a more user-friendly, interactive design without breaking up the experience with new page loads.

Also, look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Yeah that would definitely be easier. I really would rather not use form input but the project calls for giving the users a choice of music for the second page using a form on a separate page.

Comment: Why would a project call for this? Honestly, that's pointless.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. Glad you found an answer though.